# Meson can't detect boost (or any libs for that matter)

Tags: c++, boost, meson-build

I'm trying to build an old C++ server using Meson on Windows 11. To do so, I need a few libraries, including boost--however even after installing boost in two different locations (both the folder where I want to build and the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in my environment variables), when I run `meson setup build` in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt in the appropriate folder I get the following output (this is from the meson-generated log):

```
Program stderr:


Library atomic found: NO
Pkg-config binary for 1 is not cached.
Pkg-config binary missing from cross or native file, or env var undefined.
Trying a default Pkg-config fallback at pkg-config
Found pkg-config: c:\devkitPro\msys2\usr\bin\pkg-config.EXE (0.29.2)
Determining dependency 'boost' with pkg-config executable 'c:\\devkitPro\\msys2\\usr\\bin\\pkg-config.EXE'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133
Called `c:\devkitPro\msys2\usr\bin\pkg-config.EXE --modversion boost` -> 1
stderr:
Package boost was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `boost.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'boost' found
-----------
Checking potential boost root C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133
Checking potential boost root C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.19041.0
Checking potential boost root C:/Users/maier/Desktop/Yugioh AI Project/Multirole-master
Run-time dependency Boost found: NO (tried system)

meson.build:11:14: ERROR: Dependency "boost" not found, tried system
```

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from here--how can I get my system to recognize boost (and other C++ libraries)?

Comment: ¿Have you tried `Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'boost.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable` suggestion?

Comment: The error message is literally telling you what to do. Now either 1) you've tried that and it didn't work, in which case you should mention that in the question or 2) you don't know how to do this, in which case that information should be in the question 3) you didn't read the error message.

Comment: I thought I handled that implicitly when I installed it in the directory that my `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` points to--is there an additional step?